# How to use html5 picture tag and Bootstrap together

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted for a long time to have more control over my pictures on different viewports. I did not knew about the `<picture>` tag in html5.

I am working with Bootstrap 3. But does it make sense to use those Bootstrap and `<picture>` tag together? I cannot see that it is doing something in the testcode I made.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TEMPLATE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
</style>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Test row 1 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 991px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/991.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/768.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 380px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/380.jpg">
        <img src="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg" alt="Test picture" style="width:auto;">
      </picture>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Test row 2 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 991px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/991.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/768.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 380px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/380.jpg">
        <img src="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg" alt="Test picture" style="width:auto;">
      </picture>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 991px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/991.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/768.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 380px)" srcset="http://vouzalis.dk/380.jpg">
        <img src="http://vouzalis.dk/1024.jpg" alt="Test picture" style="width:auto;">
      </picture>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But does it make sense to use those Bootstrap and  tag

IMHO it probably depends on whether or not you are using a CMS that could alternatively create scaled images/thumbs for you dynamically and also how many images you're going to be loading into the page.

If it's only a few images and you're coding in static html I would just load one image and use Bootstrap's fluid-img class to control the image output. Otherwise I don't see any issue with using  as you are.